# command line cURL to PHP cURL

Tags: php, curl

```
curl -H 'content-type: application/json' --insecure -d '{"client_id":"w44p0d00.apps.2do2go", "client_secret":"mvlldlsfKLLSczxc12Kcks910cccs", "grant_type":"client_credentials", "scope": "anonymous"}' https://someurl.com/oauth/token
```

This command line cURL works perfectly. How I can do the same in PHP?

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://someurl.com/oauth/token'); //this my url
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('content-type: application/json')); //its -H
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is equivalent to your `--insecure` param:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
```

Its equivalent to your `-d` param at where you are posting json object.

```
$json = '{"client_id":"w44p0d00.apps.2do2go", "client_secret":"mvlldlsfKLLSczxc12Kcks910cccs", "grant_type":"client_credentials", "scope": "anonymous"}';
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $json);
```

After adding these to your existing curl, do the below to perform the curl and print the data:

```
$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
print $response;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$url = 'https://someurl.com/oauth/token';
$fields = array(
    'client_id' => urlencode("w44p0d00.apps.2do2go"),
     ....
);


foreach($fields as $key=>$value) { $fields_string .= $key.'='.$value.'&'; }
rtrim($fields_string, '&');

//open connection
$ch = curl_init();

//set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('content-type: application/json'));
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, count($fields));
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields_string);

//execute post
$result = curl_exec($ch);

//close connection
curl_close($ch);
```